# Is there any way to print pyramid star pattern with single line of logic code ? Interviewer asked this Question to my friend

Tags: c++

One of my friend was asked by a interviewer to print pyramid pattern using single line of logic code.
If it is possible then please provide me the solution.

Comment: What is the pyramid pattern?

Comment: Note that the complete program must be more than one line.  There needs to be at least one #include line to define the printing functions, and then the rest of the code can all be on one line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Display Pyramid using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738935/how-to-display-pyramid-using-javascript)

Comment: @Krishnanand Pathak You can initialize an object of the type std::string with the pattern and output the string.

Comment: @Martin, one could declare the printing function (`puts()` or `printf()`, I guess) oneself instead of using a header to do it.  I don't recommend that, but in golf all is fair...

Comment: I hope you and your friend avoid the company that ask such questions. The world needs a lot more software engineers who produce elegant, easy to read, and easy to maintain code than hackers.

Answer (score 4):

> If it is possible...

Yes, it is possible.

One has to cheat by hand adding the declaration out of the header file.  And by using "everything on one line" hard to read formatting, rather than maintainable formatting.

Those are silly constraints, though.  Not used in real projects.

> ...then please provide me the solution.

```
extern "C" int puts(const char *s); int main() { puts("     *\n    * *\n   *   *\n  *     *\n *       *\n***********\n"); }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do it in C++ within one line of code.
The only statement needed inside a `main()` function to print the "pyramid" (or star)  pattern is:

```
for (std::string s = "*"; s.size() < 11; s.append("*")) std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

The output is:ld be made "One line long"; just group every statement one after another. Also, what if

```
*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
***                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
****                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
*****                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
******                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
*******                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
********                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
*********                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
**********
```

*OBS:* If you want to compile it yourself, you should include the proper headers for that. Of course, this will make your source code file more than one line long (it couldn't be different, right), but the `main()` function would still consist of one single line. Also, note that the stop condition is arbitrary (in this case I set it to 10).

The full code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  for (std::string s = "*"; s.size() < 11; s.append("*")) std::cout << s << std::endl;

}
```

**DISCLAIMER**

I'm assuming that "one line of code" really means "one single statement", which is the only meaningful question to be asked. "One line of code" is very subjective. C++ doesn't care about spaces/returns, hence, every code could be made "One line long"; just group every statement one after another. Also, what if my definition of "line", which might be 'a 60-characters long sequence', differs from that of the manager, which might be 'a 40-characters long sequence'? Then a code working on my view of "single line" might not work in "manager's single line". Hence, due to the subjectivity of such definition, the only proper thing to ask is to do it in a single **statement** (or expression), which is what this answer accomplishes.

Now regarding the shape. As far as I am concerned, the "Pyramid pattern", also known as the "Star pattern", isn't exactly a pyramid. Everytime I saw this kind of puzzle, it's been concerned about this "right-angled triangle", and I'm quite sure that this is what was asked in the interview. In fact, drawing a real "pyramid" is quite difficult, since it is a 3D geometry that needs 4 triangles and one square. Hence, regarding definitions, neither my answer nor the other one draws a real **pyramid** (actually, both print a triangle). Taking into account the programming-world experience, this puzzle is about printing the "star pattern", which is more like the right-angled triangle above.

Comment: Love the second paragraph of the disclaimer. Downvote converted to upvote.